# python match time format from re

Tags: python, regex

In the following string, how can I write a regular expression with respect to time. The output should be the timestamps only.

```
 l1=May 30, 2012 at 8:13 AM  Comment · 1Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark
 l2=yesterday at 12:13 AM  2Comment  Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark
 l3=Two days ago at 01:18 AM  Comment · 5Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark
 l4=Two days ago at 15:54 PM  Comment · Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark
```

`EDIT`

```
 l5=Two days ago at 15:54:51 PM · Comment · Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark
```

Output:

```
 array1 = [May 30, 2012 at 8:13 AM ,yesterday at 12:13 AM ,Two days ago at 01:18 AM,Two days ago at 15:54 PM]

 array2=[Comment · 1Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark,2Comment · Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark,Comment · 5Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark,Comment · Like Unlike · Bookmark Unbookmark]
```

**EDIT:**

```
p_date = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}[:]\d{1,2}) but i wasnt sure how to do it if the timestamp was also like 23:12:29
```

Comment: This is not valid Python. Please show some effort.

Comment: p_date = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}[:]\d{1,2}) but i wasnt sure how to do it if the timestamp was also like 23:12:29

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'l\d+=(.*?)·(.*)'
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = []
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
    m = re.match(pattern, line)
    if m:
        l1.append(m.groups()[0])
        l2.append(m.groups()[1])


>>> l1
['May 30, 2012 at 8:13 AM ', 'yesterday at 12:13 AM ', 'Two days ago at 01:18 AM ', 'Two days ago at 15:54 PM ']
>>> l2
[' Comment \xb7 1Like Unlike \xb7 Bookmark Unbookmark', ' 2Comment \xb7 Like Unlike \xb7 Bookmark Unbookmark', ' Comment \xb7 5Like Unlike \xb7 Bookmark Unbookmark', ' Comment \xb7 Like Unlike \xb7 Bookmark Unbookmark']
>>>
```

**EDIT** : added the matching of `l1=` to remove it from matching.

Comment: What if also i have timestamps like 23:31:39 ??

Comment: @Rajeev: Have you actually tried his solution? Why are you not happy with it?

Comment: No problem as long as it's between `=` and `·`.

Comment: @Rajeev: Yes it can. At least in your examples, it can. So please correct your question. It's still invalid Python, and it's useless trying to answer a question when it's not even clear what the actual question *is*.

Comment: Yes  i have removed the '.' that was separating the text.

Comment: @Rajeev: This is leading nowhere. *All* the Python code in your question is still syntactically invalid. You *still* haven't *defined clearly*  what *exactly*  you're expecting to split your strings on. Given this, it's impossible to answer your question with reasonable accuracy. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your output by "." , if your input format is consistent.
Applying regular expressions to identify differently formed timestamp strings may be hectic task.